# How to access ChangeSets in Eclipse (Mylyn/Team)?

Tags: java, version-control, mylyn, changeset

I want to **access the ChangeSets of SVN, CVS and Git programatically via Java**. I.e. I want the data which is shown in the **"Synchronize"-view**.

I tried several approaches to find the correct usage in the code, and here's the few documentation I could find  (but without success):

- I managed to access the Synchronize-View via `TeamUI.getSynchronizeManager()`, but not the changesets.
- An other thing I tried was to get the cangesets via `FocusedTeamUiPlugin.getDefault().getContextChangeSetManagers()` (got the manager and then the ChangeSetProvider where I tried to get the ChangeSets) - but they always are empty (because they are created when I first call it).

So, how can I access ChangeSets (with Java) in Eclipse (Mylyn)? **In the end, I need the number of commits and code churn (loC added/removed/edited)**. Or is there probably an other, better approach?

Any help is appreciated really much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Eclipse has implemented this feature as a public API yet. However, these links may help:

Internal changeset class and other API: http://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api/index.html?org/eclipse/team/internal/core/subscribers/ChangeSet.html

A feature enhancement request where they talk about why they haven't implemented it yet (but it's dated 2008, however the bug is still open?) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=116084

Sorry I couldn't be of more help! Maybe this will help you in the right direction...

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps go around Eclipse:

- Apply rsync to get the CVS "*,v" files from the CVS server. It works for me.
- Apply [cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/)'s "cvs2git" command to the CVS repos. It works for me.
- Apply "git svn clone" (documented under "git-svn") to the SVN repos. I have not tried it.
- Finally, use [JGit's API](http://jgit.info/javadoc/) to get the changesets from all of the repos, which at this point are all git repos. I think you'll particularly need these:

  - class Git
  - class FileResolver
  - class BaseConnection
  - interface Repository
  - class CheckoutCommand
  - class LogCommand
  - class RevCommit
  - class DiffCommand
  - class DiffEntry
  - class DiffFormatter

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I've looking for this for 1 month now.
I tried to programm a plugin for eclipse, which is able to read the changeset of a Project ("working copy" of the repository).

What I've done now is an ugly work-around.

I used Runtime.exec() to run a cmd-command / Shell- command.
If you install a svn-commandline Client, you can type `svn status -v -u`
It gives you a list of all files of the working copy with the changeset info.

Then you can parse through the list to find all lines which start with "M" - for "modified" to get the Path of the changed file.